# How to remove VLOOKUP function in Excel and retain the cell value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using Pandas to load data from an Excel file. However, the data is lookup from another Excel file.

Is it possible to retain the cell value and remove the VLOOKUP function?

I am using:

- Excel (Microsoft 365)
- Windows 10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would just select the cells then copy : paste.special values and that will leave you the result of each vlookup. Do this for the row, column or cell as needed.